# Laravel 5 - Route Controller Error

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller, routes

I am having troubles with connecting one of my routes to its associate controller function.

**Routes file**

```
Route::get('/transaction/export','TransactionController@exporter');
```

**Controller and Function**

```
class TransactionController extends Controller
{   

    public function exporter(){
        dd("works");//-->Not seen :(
        return view('admin.transactionExport');
    }
}
```

**Link in view**

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('TransactionController@exporter')}}">Export</a>
```

When clicking on the link, the address bar in the browser shows the expected url '/transaction/export', but unfortunately it shows me a blank page. It is as though the function in the Routes file does not link to the proper controller. I have over 30 successful links in this site, and have no idea why this is failing on me right now.

Would appreciate the help. Please inform me if more information is needed to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Change your route to match the controller:

```
Route::get('/transaction/exporter', 'TransactionController@exporter');
```

Your previous route wasn't matching 'exporter'.

Comment: actually the link in the view page is successfully created and browser takes me to the intended link, but im presented a blank page as though there is no controller hooked up.

I know this is my question, but @Rottingham I would advise you to start using URL::action() for your projects. Its neater in my opinion.

Comment: Is there a URL that is reachable before the /transaction/export? such as / root in the routes.php file?

Comment: And I'll test the URL::action() method, I've not used it in the blade templates themselves but I can see the value.

Comment: all my routes are reachable and are reach their intended controllers.

Comment: Am I using a reserved keyword?

Comment: is the URL going to /transaction/exporter or /transaction/export? You said it goes to /export and your ROUTE is looking for /export but your controller is EXPORTER. This is a weird one. I'm going to go test this on a sample laravel install.

Comment: the url shows me /transaction/export. I changed the URL on the get to exporter but there is no difference, I get the same blank page.

Comment: Shrug. I would try url('/transaction/exporter') and see what happens. My test here using URL::action('TestController@index') simply creates a link to /test which doesn't work correctly.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Tune in to see if anyone manages to answer this. :p much appreciated